# i cannot access the value inside a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Here is my code **:**

```
let namesList = ref([]);

const GetFormData = (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    api
      .get("api.php", { params: { search: payload } })
      .then((response) => {
        data.value = response.data;

        // console.log(data.value);
        // convert array objects to array strings
        namesList = data.value.map(function (list) {
          return list["first_name"];
        });
        // console.log(namesList);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

If I console the `namelist` inside the function it returns the value **:**

```
(9) ['Michael Angelodfsed', 'Mardin', 'Joemar', 'Chirs', 'chan', 'loys', 'Lorena', 'kayabusa', 'kayabusa']
0: "Michael Angelodfsed"
1: "Mardin"
2: "Joemar"
3: "Chirs"
4: "chan"
5: "loys"
6: "Lorena"
7: "kayabusa"
8: "kayabusa"
length: 9
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

but if I console the variable outside the function it gives me this `console.log(nameList);`

```
RefImpl {__v_isShallow: false, dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: Array(0), _value: Proxy}
dep: Set(1) {ReactiveEffect}
__v_isRef: true
__v_isShallow: false
_rawValue: []
_value: Proxy
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
value: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

please help me guys. really struggling here. really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you are trying to access the function before the API call ends..

Comment: but how can i store the value inside the function to a variable outside the function? thanks -@Deepak

Comment: You are doing that already. Just console.log the `nameList` outside the function after your API call ends, maybe using a boolean variable..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

```js
consf nameList = ref([])

console.log(nameList.value) // get value
nameList.value = ["Shin"] // set value
```

Comment: thanks. but not even a function

Answer (score 0):

As @Deepak stated, you are trying to access the variable before the function (the api call) ends.
Your `namesList` is a `ref` object, so when you log it before it ends, it logs the object.

As your function is calling an api and use a Promise, you can change your function code to this:

```
const GetFormData = (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    api
      .get("api.php", { params: { search: payload } })
      .then((response) => {
        data.value = response.data;

        // console.log(data.value);
        // convert array objects to array strings
        namesList = data.value.map(function (list) {
          return list["first_name"];
        });
        // console.log(namesList);
        resolve(namesList);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

GetFormData(payload).then(data => console.log(data))
```